# TYPO3: Navigation with different colors

Tags: colors, navigation, typo3

Hy everyone. I am an neebie in Typo3 and i want to ask how is this possible to make a navigation with different colors. It must look like that

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="next1.html" class="red">NavItem 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">SubItem1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">SubsubItem1</a></li> <--- when active to red

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">SubItem2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">SubsubItem2.1</a></li><--- when active to red
                    <li><a href="">SubsubItem2.2</a></li><--- when active to red
                    <li><a href="" class="red active">SubsubItem2.3</a></li><--- when active to red

                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="" class="blue">NavItem 2</a></li><--- third level item to blue on active
    <li><a href="" class="green">NavItem 3</a></li><--- third level Item to green on active
    <li><a href="" class="orange">NavItem 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="purple">NavItem 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="lightblue">NavItem 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

All other third level Items must be in the specified color when they active. 
Is this possible in Typo3?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: How are the colors supposed to be assigned to the menu items? Simply by position (1st item red, 2nd item blue, etc.)? Do you actually need the same color (CSS class) assigned on the subitems? Wouldn't it be enough that the class on the 1st level item affects the subitems?

Comment: I set the color on first level with the ATagParams. Yes they are the same colors. Yes, its the point! I need the same colors on third level.

Comment: First of all: It is possible. But can you edit your question and add the typoscript part that creates the navigation (HMENU). It makes giving an answer easier.

Comment: I find a good solution with jQuery. Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: @BengoCholomongo If you found an answer to your question, you can answer your own question. This might help others who have the same question and question is marked as done.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is [optionSplit](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/3/).

f.e.

```
1.NO.ATagParams = class="red" || class="blue" || class="green" ...
```

The `||` indicates optionSplit - it will split each menu item.

I am not sure, if optionSplit works on `ATagParams`, at least you can use it on `wrapItemAndSub` or `allWrap`.

```
1.NO.allWrap = <li class="red">|</li> || <li class="blue">|</li> || ...
```